# Selecting text while jumping with cursor in iTerm2

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, iterm

I would like to know if it is possible to get text-editor-like functionality for selecting text in iTerm2.  For example, in Sublime Text 3, I can do the following:

<kbd>⇧ ⌥ →</kbd> = Select word to the right of the cursor.

<kbd>⇧ ⌘ →</kbd> = Select entire line to the right of the cursor.

But I cannot for the life of me seem to do this in iTerm2.  I can add actions that make my cursor [jump over words, or jump to the end of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10485061/778572), **but not jump *and* select at the same time.**

To be clear: I am not looking for an *alternative* to highlighting text in this manner (for example any method that begins with a <kbd>⌘ F</kbd> search or that requires a mouse), I am looking for the exact functionality outlined above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can setup key shortcuts for this functionality in iTerm2.

> In Prefs > Profiles > Keys you can assign keys to move the beginning or end of the selection by a single character, word, or line. No such keys are bound by default.

To make a shortcut for the precise text selection you are referring to you would assign the shortcuts to the following actions,

`⇧ ⌥ →` = `Move end of selection forward, Move by word`

`⇧ ⌘ →` = `Move end of selection forward, Move by line`

[image: Move end of selection forward, move by word]
[image: Move end of selection forward, move by word]

Source: https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html

Comment: I will accept this answer as it is clearly as good as we're going to get. *BUT*, readers should be aware that the functionality detailed here may be different from what they might expect.

Comment: a) “Move by line” is basically unusable to people expecting text-editor-like functionality *only* within the user-editable portion of the command line.

Comment: b) Most Mac users may like this, but separating the moving of the selection into "start" and "end" parts means that at best you can only get native Mac-style selection-moving when mixing back and forward selection-moves, rather than the (more Windows and Linux-centric?) convention used by Sublime Text.  (This is hard to explain — try it out to see what I mean.)