# Select last part of a string in iTerm2 using standard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, iterm

Using iTerm2, I am currently typing this command (notice the cursor at the end of `addons`):

[image]

If my terminal would be like any other text input I use on my Mac, I could use the shortcut `Alt` + `Shift` + `left arrow` to select the word `addons`. This is why I use the natural text editing key mapping in iTerm2, to be like other text editing tools.

However, I cannot find how to get the same behavior on iTerm2, which I would like to result in this after using the shortcut:

[image]

Is there any way to get this behavior using key mappings or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting text while jumping with cursor in iTerm2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230253/selecting-text-while-jumping-with-cursor-in-iterm2)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this link, no it doesn't after trying it out. The selection doesn't happen on the right word but the space backwards/afterwards.